# ProxySQL backends always online never shunned

Tags: mariadb, galera, proxysql

I'm trying to setup simple proxy to galera cluster via proxysql. Backend nodes and proxysql all in docker. Proxy works ok, except monitoring. When i stop mariadb on one node, proxysql still shows the node as ONLINE.

I've tried:

- Create monitoring user. This seems to work fine.
- Load configuration to runtime.
- SET mysql-connect_timeout_server_max=20000;
- UPDATE mysql_servers SET max_latency_ms=30 WHERE hostname='10.77.250.25';
- UPDATE mysql_servers SET max_replication_lag=30 WHERE hostname='10.77.250.25';

Output from proxysql admin console:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql_servers;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+---------+
| hostgroup_id | hostname     | port | gtid_port | status | weight | compression | max_connections | max_replication_lag | use_ssl | max_latency_ms | comment |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+---------+
| 10           | 10.77.250.27 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE | 1      | 0           | 100             | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 20           | 10.77.250.25 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE | 1      | 0           | 100             | 30                  | 0       | 30             |         |
| 20           | 10.77.250.26 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE | 1      | 0           | 100             | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 20           | 10.77.250.27 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE | 1      | 0           | 100             | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select hostname,from_unixtime(time_start_us/1000000) as last_check ,ping_error as error from monitor.mysql_server_ping_log group by hostname order by time_start_us desc;
+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| hostname     | last_check          | error                                                 |
+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 10.77.250.25 | 2021-11-18 21:01:07 | Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.77.250.25' (115) |
| 10.77.250.26 | 2021-11-18 21:01:07 | NULL                                                  |
| 10.77.250.27 | 2021-11-18 21:01:07 | NULL                                                  |
+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I should look in runtime_mysql_servers, not mysql_servers.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM runtime_mysql_servers;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+---------+
| hostgroup_id | hostname     | port | gtid_port | status  | weight | compression | max_connections | max_replication_lag | use_ssl | max_latency_ms | comment |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+---------+
| 10           | 10.77.250.27 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE  | 1      | 0           | 100             | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 20           | 10.77.250.27 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE  | 1      | 0           | 100             | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 20           | 10.77.250.26 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE  | 1      | 0           | 100             | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 20           | 10.77.250.25 | 3306 | 0         | SHUNNED | 1      | 0           | 100             | 30                  | 0       | 30             |         |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```